# How to install Application Server role on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm updating requirements for a software product for Windows Server 2016.

In 2012 R2 I always used to install the "**Application Server**" **role**.

This seems to have vanished in 2016. I've been searching TechNet and Microsoft forums for an answer, but I've not found one.

Is there an official document somewhere, that indicates where these features have moved to, or if they've been discontinued and permanently removed.

Specifically I'm looking for these Windows 2012R2 features in 2016:

- AS-Incoming-Trans
- AS-Outgoing-Trans
- AS-HTTP-Activation
- AS-Web-Support
- AS-WAS-Support

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I finally found something.

It's [officially deprecated][1]. I still don't know what the replacement/equivalent features are though.

  [1]: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303411.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Application Server role has been deprecated](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303411.aspx) in Windows Server 2012 R2 as you already noted, though there is no indication as to where role features are moved or how they are named now. Documentation just says: "The Application Server role is deprecated and will eventually no longer be available as an installable server role. Instead, install individual features and roles separately."

Though by looking at Server 2012 R2 installation I was able to find all the features you mentioned anyway, but it seems it is in Server 2016 where we see "no longer be available as an installable server role" part really implemented - so there out of all role features/components mentioned by you I was only able to find that **AS-WAS-Support** from 2012 R2 renamed to **WAS** in Server 2016 this one is exactly what you need, i.e. Windows Process Activation and it includes exactly the same sub components in Server 2016. Screenshot of **Get-WindowsFeature** output:

[image]

If you execute **Dism /online /Get-Features** you also should be able to see WAS* features somewhere in between other IIS* features:

[image]

I think some functionality could have been merged into other features but maybe not. If you have software product requiring this role likely it does not have support  for recently RTMed Server 2016 - you may work with vendor to get statement on supportability, if you have access to MSFT support just request them for information about where are all the features mentioned by you in Server 2016 and whether they all were they all removed or what.

Based on how it is worded in documentation mentioned above it is quite valid to ask MSFT to update their documentation to explain exactly where all the sub-components in Server 2016 as it does not seem to be the case that we can "install individual features and roles separately".

Additional section of MSFT documentation "[Features Removed or Deprecated in Windows Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/get-started/deprecated-features)" does not add any clarifications on Application Server role, referring back to the list of what has been deprecated in 2012 R2 & 2012.

Comment: `dism.exe /online /get-features` does not list 'WAS' or 'Windows Process Activation' as available features to install.

Comment: @spuder I've added screenshots demonstrating WAS features in the dism.exe /online /get-features output - just look more carefully or pipe output into text file and perform search with text editor to find them.

Answer (score 0):

For DTC inbound and outbound transactions, these appear to be configurable via Powershell, with `get-dtcnetworksetting` and `set-dtcnetworksetting` in the `msdtc` module. For example:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-dtcnetworksetting

AuthenticationLevel               : Mutual
InboundTransactionsEnabled        : False
OutboundTransactionsEnabled       : False
RemoteClientAccessEnabled         : False
RemoteAdministrationAccessEnabled : False
XATransactionsEnabled             : False
LUTransactionsEnabled             : True

PS C:\Windows\system32> set-dtcnetworksetting -inboundtransactionsenabled $true -outboundtransactionsenabled -remoteclientaccessenabled $true

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
This operation requires stopping and starting DTC to apply the changes.
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-dtcnetworksetting

AuthenticationLevel               : Mutual
InboundTransactionsEnabled        : True
OutboundTransactionsEnabled       : True
RemoteClientAccessEnabled         : True
RemoteAdministrationAccessEnabled : False
XATransactionsEnabled             : False
LUTransactionsEnabled             : True
```

There's a number of PS commands for DTC in Server 2016, see `get-command -module msdtc` for the full list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search Allow an app through Windows Firewall
2. Enable COM+ Network Access.
3. Run Regedit
4. Go to the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\COM3`
5. Change the value of `RemoteAccessEnabled` to 1.